# Replace pattern with part of matched string from the sameline in bash

Tags: json, awk, sed, stream, jq

I have a file with one json per line of the following format:

```
{"id":13, "url":"https://sub.domain.com/path", "dm":"-", "ip":"192.168.0.1"}
{"id":14, "url":"sub.domain2.com/?param=value", "dm":"-", "ip":"192.168.0.1"}
{"id":15, "url":"domain.com/path", "dm":"prefilled.com", "ip":"192.168.0.1"}
```

and I need to replace "dm":"-" with the respective domain from the same line to get this output:

```
{"id":13, "url":"https://sub.domain.com/path", "dm":"sub.domain.com", "ip":"192.168.0.1"}
{"id":14, "url":"sub.domain2.com/?param=value", "dm":"sub.domain2.com", "ip":"192.168.0.1"}
{"id":15, "url":"domain.com/path", "dm":"prefilled.com", "ip":"192.168.0.1"}
```

with any bash commands only for the lines that have "dm":"-" in an optimized way as the files are more than 10k lines long

Comment: Did you look into using `jq` ?

Comment: I am looking into it now. I have edited to question to reflect that the file is a log of json events, one per line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU or OSX sed for ERE support via `-E`:

```
$ sed -E 's#(.*"url":"([^"]+\/\/)?([^"/]+).*"dm":")-"#\1\3"#' file
{"id":13, "url":"https://sub.domain.com/path", "dm":"sub.domain.com", "ip":"192.168.0.1"}
{"id":14, "url":"sub.domain2.com/?param=value", "dm":"sub.domain2.com", "ip":"192.168.0.1"}
{"id":15, "url":"domain.com/path", "dm":"domain.com", "ip":"192.168.0.1"}
```

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(.*"url":"([^"]+\/\/)?([^"/]+).*"dm":")-(".*)/,a){$0=a[1] a[3] a[4]} 1' file
{"id":13, "url":"https://sub.domain.com/path", "dm":"sub.domain.com", "ip":"192.168.0.1"}
{"id":14, "url":"sub.domain2.com/?param=value", "dm":"sub.domain2.com", "ip":"192.168.0.1"}
{"id":15, "url":"domain.com/path", "dm":"domain.com", "ip":"192.168.0.1"}
```

Comment: this works! One question though, how to do it only for the lines which have "dm":"-" ?

Comment: Thank you for your support. I edited the question to reflect the accepted answer.

Comment: Works. Plus one for the guy who teached me so much about `awk` (In the hope that once you'll like `jq` as much as I do ;) )

Comment: Thanks! So far I haven't personally come across anything in json that I need to parse from the command-line but I'm sure some day..... of course by then hopefully there'll be a gawk library for it :-).

Answer (score 4):

With `jq-1.5` (the most recent version atm) you can do:

```
jq 'if .dm == "-" then .dm = (.url|sub("https?://";"")|sub("/.*";"")) else . end' a.json
```

Explanation:

```
if .dm == "-" ...           # Runs the following only if .dm exists and it's value is "-"
.dm=(...)                   # Assigns to .dm
.url|sub("^https?://"; "")  # Takes .url and replaces http/https:// from the beginning
...|sub("/.*"; "")          # Replaces everything after the first / (including it)
```

Comment: Looks like the OP had a hidden requirement, see his comment under [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43897717/1745001): `how to do it only for the lines which have "dm":"-"`. What does that look like with `jq`?

Comment: Just  searching for a nice way with `jq`. Actually I was about to recommend Python, which is imo the cleanest approach on the Linux terminal. Give me some time.

Comment: OK, I really am interested in seeing if/how `jq` handles this though.

Comment: I think is somethink like this: jq 'map(select(.dm == "-") | .dm = (.url|sub("^https?://";"")|sub("/.*";"")))' a.json

Comment: @Jinxmcg Looks like you don't need help, since you seem to have good jq skills! :) .. Almost correct, but is should be `jq 'if .dm == "-" then .dm = (.url|sub("https?://";"")|sub("/.*";"")) else . end'`

Comment: @EdMorton ^^^^ look, here

Comment: I did not know about jq before posting this question...:( seems like a great tool which I will definitively use it in the future.

Comment: @Jinxmcg: If you're looking to operate on json data on the command line, _the_ answer should always involve `jq`, it was designed for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed to do it, but I'd suggest you to use something that actually comprehends the data if there is any variation in the format:

```
sed -i -r 's/^(.*"url":")(.*\/\/)?(.*)(\/.*)"-"/\1\2\3\4"\3"/g' your_file
```

Comment: What is `.*?` supposed to mean? If it's intended to be some kind of look-around, sed doesn't support them.

Comment: `sed` with extended regex flag ought to support non-greedy matching. Just tested it and it works as expected.

Comment: No, non-greedy matching is not part of EREs, that's part of PCREs which no sed supports. If you're getting the output you expect then it's for some other reason.

Comment: Spoke too soon... You're right, but for the file contents in question greedy matching will work.